# Very slow query planning time with many indexes

Tags: postgresql

I have a table "nodes" with a JSONB-column "data", in which I store various types of information.

The JSON includes pieces of text in different languages, that need to be frequently searched on by end-users. Per language, I therefore create about 4 indices similar to the following (usually with a separate search dictionary for that language)

```
CREATE INDEX nodes_label_sv_idx
    ON nodes
        USING GIN (to_tsvector('swedish_text', data #>> '{label,sv}'));
```

This works fine when only 2 or 3 languages are present, but when adding 20 more languages (each with 4 indices for that language's path into the JSON), the query planner becomes extremely slow for some queries (180 ms), even though those queries are still executing very fast (less than 1ms). The table currently contains about 50K records.

Weird thing is, those queries are simple joins on other columns of the table (unrelated to the "data" column), so the language-related indices are completely irrelevant. Also, the more language-related indices I drop, the faster the planner becomes again.

I completely understand that the planner needs to check all (150+) indices for potential relevance, but 180ms is extreme. Anybody have a suggestion? By the way, the problem only seems to occur when using a view (not when directly using the query underlying the view).

I am using PostgresSQL 13 on Mac & Linux.

Edit:

query:

```
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)
select 1
from ca_nodes can
where (can.owner_id = 168 or can.aco_id = 0)
limit 1;
```

underlying view:

```
CREATE VIEW ca_nodes AS
SELECT n.nid, n.owner_id, c.aco_id, 
FROM nodes n inner join acos c on n.nid = c.nid;
```

explain (analyze, buffers) output:

```
Limit  (cost=0.58..32.45 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.038..0.039 rows=1 loops=1)
  Buffers: shared hit=6
  ->  Merge Join  (cost=0.58..15136.78 rows=475 width=4) (actual time=0.037..0.037 rows=1 loops=1)
        Merge Cond: (n.nid = c.nid)
        Join Filter: ((n.owner_id = 168) OR (c.aco_id = 0))
        Buffers: shared hit=6
        ->  Index Scan using nodes_pkey on nodes n  (cost=0.29..12094.35 rows=47604 width=8) (actual time=0.017..0.017 rows=1 loops=1)
              Buffers: shared hit=3
        ->  Index Scan using acos_nid_idx on precalculated_acos c  (cost=0.29..2090.35 rows=47604 width=8) (actual time=0.014..0.014 rows=1 loops=1)
              Buffers: shared hit=3
Planning:
  Buffers: shared hit=83
Planning Time: 180.392 ms
Execution Time: 0.079 ms
```

Comment: Please show `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` for one of these slow executions.

Comment: I don't get anywhere near this bad.  Is this reproducible?  Is it only on the first call for each session or all the time?  Can you share the entire schema (`pg_dump -s`)?

Comment: It varies a bit from call to call, but I never got it lower than 120ms.

Comment: See a more complete table definition here: https://gist.github.com/mtruyens/d98f612844ed8d3620ce394855a1a21b (the above snippets were deliberately trimmed)

Comment: In my hands, it is all the partial indexes (the ones with a WHERE clause) that makes it slow.